# How to call a function in C? Also, why is almost every line of code an error?

Tags: c, function, compiler-errors

I'm new to C and i am making this game just to practice what i know already. I don't quite understand how to make the code go from one function to another function (maybe called calling the function?). I have compiled and tested it a few times but each time at least one thing didn't work and I went on blindly (probably not a good idea) and now I CANNOT go on. It is not finished.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
    int response;
    int loyalty = 0;
    int level = 1;
    int howmany;
    int dothemnow;
    int squad1;
    int responsetwo;
    int pushup;
    char name [20];
int main(){
        pushup=1;
        dothemnow=0;
        howmany=0;
        printf ("Welcome to Game1\n");
        printf ("What's your name?\n");
        scanf ("%s",name);
        printf ("From now on you're Private %s\n",name);
        printf ("Loading...\n");
        sleep (2);
        printf("You are in a army excersize yard.\n");
        sleep (2);
        printf("Your sargeant approaches.\n");
        sleep (2);
        printf ("Sargeant Sam: Drop and give me five, Private %s\n",name);
        printf ("1)Yessir!\n2)Make me\n");
        scanf ("%d", &response);
            if(response==1){
                while(howmany<4 && pushup==1){
                    printf ("You do a pushup.\n");
                    howmany ++;
                    sleep(1);
                    printf ("You have done %d pushups\n",howmany);
                    printf ("Do another?\n1) yes\n2) no\n");
                    scanf ("%d",&pushup);
                }
            }

                if(howmany==5){
                    /*Make it so it goes to the war function*/
                    int war();
                }
                if(pushup==2 && dothemnow!=2){
                    dothemnow ++;
                    printf("Sargeant Sam: Do them NOW!!!\n");
                    sleep(2);
                    printf ("1)Why?\n2)Ok,ok\n");
                    scanf ("%d",&responsetwo);
                }
                    if(responsetwo==1){
                        while(howmany<4 && pushup==1){
                            printf ("You do a pushup.\n");
                            howmany ++;
                            sleep(1);
                            printf ("You have done %d pushups\n",howmany);
                            printf ("Do another?\n1) yes\n2) no\n");
                            scanf ("%d",&pushup);
                        }   
                    }       
                            if(howmany==5){
                                int war();
                            }
                            if(pushup==2){
                                dothemnow ++;
                            }
                    if(responsetwo==2){
                        while(howmany<4 && pushup==1){
                            printf ("You do a pushup.\n");
                            howmany ++;
                            sleep(1);
                            printf ("You have done %d pushups\n",howmany);
                            printf ("Do another?\n1) yes\n2) no\n");
                            scanf ("%d",&pushup);                   
                    }
                        }
                            if(howmany==5){
                            int war();
                            }
                            if(pushup==2){
                            dothemnow ++;
                            }
            if(response==2){
                dothemnow ++;
                printf("Sargeant Sam: Do them NOW!!!\n");
                sleep(2);
                printf ("1)Why?\n2)Ok,ok\n");
                scanf ("%d",&responsetwo);
            }   
                if(responsetwo==1){
                    dothemnow ++;
                }   
                if(responsetwo==2)
                    while(howmany<4 && pushup==1){
                        printf ("You do a pushup.\n");
                        howmany ++;
                        sleep(1);
                        printf ("You have done %d pushups\n",howmany);
                        printf ("Do another?\n1) yes\n2) no\n");
                        scanf ("%d",&pushup);
                        if(pushup==2){
                            dothemnow ++;
                        }
                        if(howmany==5){
                            int war();
                        }   
            }


        if(dothemnow==2){
            printf ("You are under military arrest!\n");
        }
return 0;
}
int war(){
    printf ("Loading...");
    sleep (2);
    printf ("Seargant Sam: Great job Private %s.\n",name);
    sleep (2);
    printf ("You are hereby promoted to Corporal");
    sleep (2);
    printf ("****LEVEL UP!****\n");
    sleep (1);
    level ++;
    printf ("You are now level %d!\n",level);
    sleep (1);
    printf ("Do you want to be friendly or strict to your squad?\n1) Friendly\n2) Strict\n");
    scan("%d", squad1);
    if(squad1==1){
        loyalty --;
    }
    if(squad1==2)
        loyalty ++;
    }
    printf ("Seargant Sam: You will be deployed to Afganistan in one week, Corporal %s.\n",name);
    sleep (1);
    printf ("In the mean time, get to know your sqaud.\n");
    sleep (1);
    printf ("There are ten about 20 to 25 year olds in front of you\n");
    sleep (1);
    printf ("1)Nod\n2)'Laugh' Well I guess I'm the boss of you now\n3)Salute\n4)Drop and give me twenty!\n");
    scanf ("%d", &squad2);
    switch(squad2){
        case 1:
            printf ("They nod back");
        case 2:
            loyalty - 2;
            printf ("They all smile and laugh a little");
            break;


        case 3:
            loyalty + 2;
            printf ("They all salute back");
            sleep(1)
            printf ("'As you were', you say");
            break;


        case 4:
            loyalty + 3;
            printf ("They do the pushups");
            break;
    }   
    printf ("Seargant Sam: Show them to their cabin, Corporal.");
    sleep (1);
    printf("You walk to the cabin.\n");
    sleep (1);
    if(loyalty>0){
        printf ("One of the soldiers in your squad, Private Smith, who looks wiry but strong, says 'Corporal, you seem like a cool guy, but how did you get promoted to corporal?'");
        sleep (1);
        printf ("Ha, I see how you could be confused");
        sleep (1);
        printf ("Well, I don't really know either, I just did five pushups, and wahla, Corporal.");
    }




}
```

So, when i attempt to compile this I get the errors:

```
game1.c:136: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:136: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘name’
game1.c:136: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:136: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:136: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:137: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
game1.c:137: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:138: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:138: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:138: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:138: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:139: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
game1.c:139: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:140: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:140: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:140: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:140: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:141: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
game1.c:141: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:142: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:142: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:142: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:142: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:143: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:143: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
game1.c:143: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:143: error: conflicting types for ‘scanf’
game1.c:143: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:144: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘switch’
game1.c:166: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:166: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:166: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:166: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:167: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
game1.c:167: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:168: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before string constant
game1.c:168: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:168: error: conflicting types for ‘printf’
game1.c:168: note: a parameter list with an ellipsis can’t match an empty parameter name list declaration
game1.c:169: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
game1.c:169: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
game1.c:170: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘if’
game1.c:181: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
```

Notice that is doesn't say that it is in the function war.

Comment: When you see a stream of errors like that, just look at the *first* one and ignore the others. They are usually just side-effects.

Comment: Note that `printf()`, `scanf()`, and `sleep()` are all functions.  So you should call your `war()` function in exactly the same way that you call those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
 if(squad1==2)
        loyalty ++;
    }
```

You have a closing brace, but not an opening brace. This simple syntax error is causing a wave of compilation errors from this point until the end of the file.

Note that line 136, which is the point of the first reported syntax error, is the line immediately after the above snippet.